# How to filter the fullcalendar v4 cache events when call the rerenderEvents method?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to filter the already loaded data in calendar .
I can't able to figure how to do that because data is alot i dont want to do the ajax call every time . Only tutorial i was able to find show in v3 of fullcalendar but not in v4

judging by this code of v3 i can see that its returning true or false

```js
eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
        return ['all', event.school].indexOf($('#school_selector').val()) >= 0
 }
```

but when i do the same thing in v4 its not working

1. all the data for current month is loaded
2. than i click on the radio buttons so calendar show only events with a specific groupId

this is what i write for v4

**every event has groupId either school or university**

```js
eventRender: function (info) {
      if (info.event.groupId === "university") {
        console.log("event Name :" + info.event.title);
        console.log("groupId :" + info.event.groupId);

        return true;
      }
      // console.log("call :" + info.event.groupId);
    }
```

full-code here Codepen link: https://codepen.io/tsajid/pen/yLYqoBw

Comment: "when i do the same thing in v4"...please show exactly what you did, and exactly what errors/problems you are seeing (e.g. Console errors, unexpected behaviour etc). Note that in v4 the signature of the eventRender callback is different, so you need to adjust for that at least: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender

Comment: @ADyson i have updated my question please tell me why filter is not working

Comment: probably because you forgot to `return false;` if it doesn't meet your criteria. The default behaviour is to render the event. it will always render unless you tell it not to.

Comment: @ADyson when i click on school it shows university events and when click on university it shows schools events very weird bug is happening https://codepen.io/tsajid/pen/yLYqoBw

Comment: I'll repeat: The function has to return **false** if you _don't_ want to show the event. If you _do_ want to show the event you can either return nothing, or return a new HTML that element you want to replace the original one with. Returning the `info` object makes no sense at all - I'm not quite sure what you expect that will achieve? Read this comment, and my last comment, and the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) again, and then have another go.

Comment: `
 eventRender: function (info) {
     if (info.event.groupId === filter_option) {
       
        return false;
      }
    }
 `

Comment: Not really. Because a) that will return false if the filter matches (which is the opposite of what you want. You might want to think about using a "not equals" test instead), and b) you haven't taken account of the "all" option.

Comment: If you're still really stuck I can give you the solution but I think you should try it one more time - it's not that hard, and the best way to learn is by doing.

Comment: A good way to help yourself with algorithms you're struggling to implement is to think about what the test logic would be if you did this manually in your head - imagine the list of events in front of you on pieces of card, and you have to sort them according to the current filter. What attributes would you look for in order to say "yes" or "no" to a specific card? What test would you carry out? Write that process out in words, and the run through it to test it. Once you're happy with that, only then should you start trying to turn that logic into program code.

Comment: @ADysonif 
1) you can give me the solution that will be good
2) why i need to pass all because groupId is only school and university

Comment: Because when the user has the "all"option selected, if you simply check whether the groupID matches the filter option, then it **never** will (because none of the events have "all" in their group ID, do they?), so it will _hide_ all the events when "all" is selected rather than showing them - unless you make a special case for it in your `if` statement. Go on, have one more go. I've given you more than enough clues. Give it some proper thought. Use the manual design process I described above if you need to. Come back in half an hour and ask me again if you haven't made any progress.

Comment: Basically you need to be saying `if the current filter isn't "all", and the current filter doesn't match the group ID, then hide this event`. So there I've even done the logic part for you now. That should not be hard to implement in code. I can't work out if it's the raw logic, or the code part which you are struggling with really? They are two different aspects of the problem, as I've been showing you.

Comment: If you can work out the raw logic, then you should be able to implement that in _any_ programming language once you learn its syntax. And you might even be able to write several different versions of the code which implement the same abstract logic. That's why it's important to separate the logic from the code in your mind. I say this because I get the impression you were just flapping about making semi-random changes to the code, without first taking the time to work out what your changes were actually trying to achieve.

Comment: (P.S. Please don't take this personally, it's not a criticism, just an observation. It's a common mistake that inexperienced programmers make. I have done the same in the past, so I'm hoping to help you avoid doing it again in future. Just something to learn from that's all.)

Answer (score 2):

thanks to [@ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson)

```js
eventRender: function (info) {
     // filter_option might be university | school 

      if (filter_option !== "all" && info.event.groupId !== filter_option) {

        return false;
      }
```

[FullCode](https://codepen.io/tsajid/pen/yLYqoBw)